# Android Wear "complication"

Tags: android-wear

I previously had an Asus Zenwatch2. I was able to add a complication (I think that's what the little customize-able data points that can be added to certain watch faces are called) that would display the phone battery. It seemed the source for this was the Asus Zenwatch app installed on my phone.

I have upgraded to a Huawei Watch 2 Classic. I don't see an option to get this or several other useful complications that were available from the Asus app on my new watch.

I obviously don't really understand how these complications work.

Is this something that I could get in a 3rd party watchface or is it not available because it needs to be pushed from an app on the phone (like it was from the Asus app)?

Here is an example of the menu to choose a complication:

[image]